deploying rabbitmq using Helm charts On Minikube
i'm jr. on minikube adn trying to understand whole structure.
i have installed Minikube on Ubuntu 24.04.
After I have tried to deploy rabbitmq using Helm Chart but I got some issues..
Output like here:
kubectl describe pod rabbitmq-0 -n rabbitmq
enter image description here
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
enter image description here
kubectl logs rabbitmq-0 -n rabbitmq
enter image description here
Before the below solution,
the output was like that.
enter image description here
https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/z2nbw2/rabbitmq_helm_chart/
I have tried and implemented that solution but i got Readiness probe failed: and Liveness probe failed:
How can i fix those issues ?
EDIT
############################################################################
I have changed the deploy package and I have used the KinD not minikube.
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/rabbitmq
helm install my-release oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/rabbitmq
now the error got invisible .
pod works properly
my-release-rabbitmq-0 1/1 Running 0 14h
now no error.. the solution is like that ..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60407082/rabbit-mq-error-while-waiting-for-mnesia-tables
trying to fix the problems with those solutions on rabbit.

EDIT
############################################################################
I have changed the deploy package and I have used the KinD not minikube.
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/rabbitmq
helm install my-release oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/rabbitmq
now the error got invisible .
pod works properly
my-release-rabbitmq-0 1/1 Running 0 14h
now no error.. the solution is like that ..
